# find the region part of live using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, click, mschart

I have done like this for creating click event handler for one part of the chart using mschart control, the chart is like this [image]

and the code like this

```
private void targetChartmouse_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
  try
  {
    var pos = e.Location;
    var results = kpiChartControl.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
      if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
      { 
        //do something....
      }
    }        
  }
}
```

It's working fine when we click on the chart (in every section of chart), but I want to do something only when we click on the live(green), not on every part. Is it possible to find the region of live(green)

Is it possible using c#?

I am doing winforms application

Modified Code

```
     public void targetChartmouse_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
  Series statusseries = new Series();
  Series liveseries = null;
  Title title;
  string area;

  //Series totalserries;
  try
  {
    var pos = e.Location;
    var results = kpiChartControl.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
      if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
      {

          DataTable accepts = null;
          accepts = KPIData.livemembersmembershiptype(mf);

          DataTable membershiptypes = null;
          membershiptypes = KPIData.MembershipTotals(dtStartDate.Value, dtEndDate.Value, mf);

          area = "subchart";
          kpiChartControl.ChartAreas.Add(area);
          statusseries = kpiChartControl.Series.Add(area);
          statusseries.ChartArea = area;

          title = kpiChartControl.Titles.Add("Live Status  members  By MemberShip Type");
          title.DockedToChartArea = area;
          title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
          title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
          kpiChartControl.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area;
          kpiChartControl.Titles.Add("Live status membership types").DockedToChartArea = area;


          area = "";
          kpiChartControl.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area;




          foreach (Title titles in kpiChartControl.Titles)
          {
            titles.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
          }


          foreach (ChartArea chartArea in kpiChartControl.ChartAreas)
          {
            chartArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
            chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
            //chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = !overview;
          }

          if (area == "subchart")
          {
            foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
            {
              chartSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
              chartSeries["ColumnDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";
              chartSeries["LabelStyle"] = "Top";
              chartSeries.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
              chartSeries.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;
            }
          }
          else if (area == "subchart")
          {
            foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
            {
              chartSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

              //chartSeries["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
              chartSeries["PieLabelStyle"] = "Inside";
              chartSeries["DoughnutRadius"] = "30";
              chartSeries["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";

              chartSeries.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;

            }

          }

          foreach (Legend legend in kpiChartControl.Legends)
          {
            legend.Enabled = false;
          }

          if (membershiptypes == null)
          {
            statusseries.Points.Clear();
            statusseries.Points.AddXY("no status", 0);

          }
          if (accepts == null)
          {
            liveseries.Points.Clear();
            liveseries.Points.AddXY("no live", 0);

          }
          kpiChartControl.Series["subchart"].Points.DataBindXY(accepts.Rows, "mshipname", accepts.Rows, "count");
          kpiChartControl.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(membershiptypes.Rows, "Status", membershiptypes.Rows, "Value");

        }

        foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
        {
          foreach (DataPoint point in chartSeries.Points)
          {

            switch (point.AxisLabel)
            {
              case "Silver membership": point.Color = Color.Green; break;
              case "Gold Membership": point.Color = Color.Blue; break;
              //case "Refused": point.Color = Color.Red; break;
              case "Weekend Peak": point.Color = Color.Cyan; break;
              case "prspect": point.Color = Color.Indigo; break;

            }
            point.Label = string.Format("{0:0}", point.YValues[0]);
          }

        }

        foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
        {
          foreach (DataPoint point in chartSeries.Points)
          {
            switch (point.AxisLabel)
            {
              case "New": point.Color = Color.Cyan; break;
              case "Live": point.Color = Color.Green; break;
              case "Defaulter": point.Color = Color.Red; break;
              case "Cancelled": point.Color = Color.Orange; break;
              case "Completed": point.Color = Color.Blue; break;
              case "Frozen": point.Color = Color.Violet; break;
            }

            point.Label = string.Format("{0:0} - {1}", point.YValues[0], point.AxisLabel);
          }
        }

    }
  }
  catch
  {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
try
{
  var pos = e.Location;
  var results = kpiChartControl.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
  foreach (var result in results)
  {
    if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
    {
      if (result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].AxisLabel == "Live")
      {
        Console.WriteLine("success?");
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: would you pls take a look at this question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831536/set-the-footer-in-place

Comment: Dominique pls take a look at this one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can acquire the `DatePoint` using [`result.PointIndex`(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.hittestresult.pointindex.aspx) and [`result.Series`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.hittestresult.series.aspx).

```
if(result.Series.Points.Item[result.PointIndex].Label == "Live") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Updated from Series to DataPoint.

Comment: `theSeries` is the `Series` your Diagram gets feeded with. You can e.g. acquire it using `Series theSeries = theChart.Series.Item(0)`.

Comment: *What* exactly is not working? Is it not compiling? Do you get an error? Have you checked the `Label` using e.g. a MsgBox?

Comment: points .items take a look at my entire code.......in modified part in my question

Comment: Oh, a little typo, it should be just `Item`.

Comment: Please first try to do exactly: `MessageBox.Show(theSeries.Points.Item[result.PointIndex].Label);` inserted just in your first chunk of code and tell me what the messagebox shows. Comment out all the other code.

Comment: In above code which one i have to take either statusseries or liveseries

Comment: Take result.Series: `MessageBox.Show(result.Series.Points.Item[result.PointIndex].Label);`. Imho my last edit should get it to work.

Comment: what extension? When you type in exactly what I wrote, what compiler error do you get?

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection' does not contain a definition for 'item' and no extension method 'item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   this is error i have got

Comment: again. in your first snippet, instead of `// do something...`, put `MessageBox.Show(result.Series.Points.Item[result.PointIndex].Label);`. Then start the app and click on the chart. The label should be output. Place exactly this code in!